# Gitlab CI docker cannot login to docker hub

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

i have two project on gitlab with same CI config file and ci variables. When i try to build dockerfile, one project passed, but second say:

`Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device`

config:

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  
variables:
  CONTAINER_IMAGE: sleezy/go-hello-world:${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker login -u ${DOCKER_USER} -p ${DOCKER_PASSWORD}
    - docker build -t ${CONTAINER_IMAGE} .
    - docker tag ${CONTAINER_IMAGE} ${CONTAINER_IMAGE}
    - docker tag ${CONTAINER_IMAGE} sleezy/go-hello-world:latest
    - docker push ${CONTAINER_IMAGE}
```

How i said, everything is same, variables, dockerhub account - username, password, config, even gitlab runner version, so i really dont know why? Any help, thanks.

Comment: Does this [link](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Piplenes-docker-login-can-not-perform-an-interactive-login-from/qaq-p/595736) help?

Comment: I have variables in both projects

Comment: To check wether `DOCKER_USERNAME` and `DOCKER_PASSWORD` is set in the repo where the build fails you could echo them before trying to login. If these environment variables are empty the `docker login` command does not pass the name and password, which in return triggers the interactive login. As this is not possible from inside the pipeline, it fails.

Comment: Ok, so echo says thas variables are empty, but i really dont know why, cause they really set, i looked 10x times, they exists

Comment: Mhm, at least this explains the error message. Unfortunenatly I can't say more without seeing your project settings. Maybe the variable settings [ref](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#add-a-cicd-variable-to-a-project) are different for the two projects

Comment: Make sure your protected variables match your protected branches. If you have the variables as protected but the branch isn't, the expansions will be blank.